# How to make the function return to a certain place if invalid input takes place?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have a function

```
function Choice(options) {
wait()
    function wait(){ // only proceed after a selection is made;
        selection = parseInt(selectedchoice);

        if (selection < 1){

            setTimeout(wait,1000);

            console.log("Not chosen yet");

            selection = parseInt(selectedchoice);

        } 
        else if (selection == 1 || selection == 2){

            // Finding what the user selected
            for (var i in options.choices) {
                m++
                if (m === selection){
                    //console.log("PICK IS " + i);
                    pick = i;
                    break
                }
            }
            console.log(options.choices[pick].condition)
            if (selection >= options.choices.length || selection <= 0 || options.choices[pick].condition === false ) {
                selection = 0;
                //Choice(options);
                console.log("Invalid selection");
//USE MAGIC HERE


            }
            else {
                   console.log("Valid selection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the user picks an invalid selection he should be told about that and thrown a bit back to pick again. Apparently calling the function Choice(options) again, even after resetting selection to 0, causes infinite recursion. Same with throw (though I don't know how to use them properly).

The question is: how to make the programm do the function Choice() again if an error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach to this problem is wrong. You shouldn't use `setTimeout` to "watch" on a value change; instead, you should make your logic be driven by events.

In this particular, you want to attach an `change`[[doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)] event handler to your select element. Whenever your event handler is called, you will know for sure that the value of select element is changed, then you can perform actions against user's selection accordingly. For example,

HTML:

```
<select id="select" onchange="onSelectChange()">
    <option value="0">Please choose...</option>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function onSelectChange() {
    var selection = document.getElementById('select').value;

    if (/* selection is valid */) {
        // do whatever you need to do for a vaild selection
    } else {
        // selection is invalid, you want to notify user invalid
        // selection by using "alert" or something like that, and
        // you're DONE!
    }
}
```

In this way, if the selection is invalid, the user can select again, and your handler **will** run again once the user makes a different choice.

Answer (score 1):

change you `if` to a `while`

this way. While no selection occured the code stays on this block and only continues when a user made a selection

```
function Choice(options) {
wait()
 function wait() { // only proceed after a selection is made;
    selection = parseInt(selectedchoice);
    while (selection !== 1 || selection !== 2 ) {

        selection = parseInt(selectedchoice);

    }

    // Finding what the user selected
    for (var i in options.choices) {
        m++
        if (m === selection) {
            //console.log("PICK IS " + i);
            pick = i;
            break
        }
        console.log(options.choices[pick].condition)
        if (selection >= options.choices.length || selection <= 0 || options.choices[pick].condition === false) {
            selection = 0;
            //Choice(options);
            console.log("Invalid selection");
            //USE MAGIC HERE
        } else {
            console.log("Valid selection");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But what if the selection is made and it's wrong? That's the main problem here.

Comment: `setTimeout` is async, you should never use it like this.

Comment: For example let's say selection is only corrent when selection == 1 || selection == 2

Comment: let me exaplain myself. If I add checks, which is logical, everything is fine but one thing - after the program detects a wrong selection it stops operating. I am asking:"How can I make it run that function again and let the user maek his selection again?"

Comment: Its hard to say with out more code. Another way to do it bind an event to the selection like 'blur'